# Pull records from model in a custom order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an rails application with user, app and review models. When user visit app show page i am fetching all reviews for an app as `@app.reviews`

Associations . .

User -> has_many :reviews, has_many :apps

Review -> belongs_to :app, belongs_to :user

App -> has_many :reviews, belong_to :user

I would like to fetch all the reviews with the current_user review at the top/first. How can do it?

Comment: Kindly post a question in a way that can be easily understandable by everyone....:) by adding more details in depth...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you read the truly-excellent Rails Guide that covers all the details of using Rails' Query Interface? It will answer your question and also help you level up in Rails:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use ActiveRecord for this. You're already using it to get all the reviews for that particular app. You can go further and use:

```
@app.reviews.where(user_id == current_user.id)
```

where current_user was your user. The belongs_to and has_many calls put those ids in there for you to use.

Since you plan to do this so that the current_user's reviews are ordered first, you could do these steps:

1. Get all reviews for the app where the user_id != current_user.id, store in an array.
2. Find the reviews for current_user, store in another array.
3. Concatenate the two arrays with the current_user reviews first, yielding one array with all of the reviews for the app, but with the current_user reviews ordered first.